# Teradata query returns bad characters in string column but exporting to CSV from assistant console works

Tags: teradata

I am using DBI package in R to connect to `teradata` this way:

```
library(teradatasql)

query <- "
    SELECT sku, description
    FROM sku_table
    WHERE sku = '12345'
    "

dbconn <- DBI::dbConnect(
        teradatasql::TeradataDriver(),
        host = teradataHostName, database = teradataDBName,
        user = teradataUserName, password = teradataPassword
    )

dbFetch(dbSendQuery(dbconn, query), -1)
```

It returns a result as follows:

```
  SKU                               DESCRIPTION
12345      18V MAXâ×¢ Collated Drywall Screwgun
```

Notice the bad characters `â×¢` above. This is supposed to be superscript TM for trademarked.

When I use SQL assistant to run the query, and export the query results manually to a CSV file, it works fine as in the DESCRIPTION column has correct encoding.

Any idea what is going on and how I can fix this problem? Obviously, I don't want a manual step of exporting to CSV and re-reading results back into R data frame, and into memory.

Comment: The connection to the database needs to specify a Unicode client character set (UTF8 or UTF16) instead of the legacy default ASCII with Teradata LATIN extensions. If you need specific "how to" instructions you'll need to edit the question to clarify what client / connection method is being used for the "bad" result.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. You refer to sql assistant, python, and r.  What's not working? Take out what is working, it's not relevant.

Comment: Then my earlier comment got it backwards. Both those drivers always use UTF8 for connections. In that case, the data may be fine and the issue may only be that some Windows applications assume the native Windows character set for text files unless the file starts with a 3-byte Byte Order Mark signature 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF to indicate what follows is UTF8.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: The implementation of R on Windows still has some challenges with UTF8 encoded data. You may need to declare that the encoding of the result is UTF8, e.g. `encoding(...) <- "UTF-8"`to have it displayed properly.

Comment: This is on a Linux host and a Mac. The issue is not a display issue. It is how the text is and gets written the same way to a CSV. I also tried with Python and Pandas, and get the exact same result. Seems like a Teradata result encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Teradata SQL Driver for R (teradatasql package) only supports the UTF8 session character set, and does not support using the ASCII session character set with a client-side character set for encoding and decoding.

If you have stored non-LATIN characters in a CHARACTER SET LATIN column in the database, and are using a client-side character set to encode and decode those characters for the "good" case, that will not work with the teradatasql package.

On the other hand, if you used the UTF8 or UTF16 session character set to store Unicode characters into a CHARACTER SET UNICODE column in the database, then you will be able to retrieve those characters successfully using the teradatasql package.

Comment: "If you have stored non-LATIN characters in a CHARACTER SET LATIN column in the database," - The database is what it is. IF this is the problem, can I change client side settings (how?) to retrieve proper column values?

Comment: [ "IF this is the problem, can I change client side settings (how?) to retrieve proper column values?" ]

No.

Other drivers, such as the Teradata JDBC Driver, offer a CLIENT_CHARSET connection parameter to let you access non-LATIN characters stored in a CHARACTER SET LATIN column, but that is not a supported use case.

The Teradata SQL Driver for R does not offer any facility for accessing non-LATIN characters stored in a CHARACTER SET LATIN column.